# PHP percent calculation not working

Tags: php

I have this a record of: `10/2 * 100%`

This is equal to `5`

How does it save in PHP?

This not work:

```
($int1/$int2) * 100
```

Comment: Save to where? What are your vars? What are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$int1 = 10` and `$int2 = 2`, you'd have this sum;

```
echo (10 / 2) * 1; //1 being 100%
```

Which outputs 5.

http://codepad.org/twp2TduF

There is nothing wrong - it gives your desired result. I assume you were `* 100`, which would give `500`.

**Other percentages**

- `* 0.25` = 25%
- `* 0.75` = 75%
- *..and so-on*

  - Or refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010322/3000179)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use percentage this way.

You will need to divide them by 100:

```
<?php


$int1 = 3;

$int2 = 6;


echo ($int1/$int2) * 100/100;
```

this above is 100%

and this:

```
echo ($int1/$int2) * 25/100;
```

is 25%